# Параметр не передается в запрос

Tags: php, mysqli

Задача заключается в следующем, есть ссылка при нажатии на которую должно передаваться два параметра:

```
<?="<a href='?red={$task['task_type']}&id={$task['id']}#zatemnenie'>Редактировать</a>"?>
```

Мне нужно что бы по запросу обновлялись данные в БД после ввода их с формы. Я делаю вот такой запрос:

```
if ($_POST[red] === 'redTask'){
    $redtt = mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE `tasks` SET `obc`='{$_POST['obc']}', `sr`='{$_POST['sr']}', `osr`='{'$_POST['osr']'}' WHERE `id`={$_GET['id']}");
}
```

Но обновления не происходит. Когда я задаю id конкретным числом, обновления происходит при отправке формы. Если я вывожу параметр id просто в `echo $_GET['id'];` нужный айдишник отображается. Почему это так происходит и как это исправит ?

Comment: Так это гет запрос.... Вместо `$_POST['red']` надо использовать `$_GET['red']`

Comment: Аналогично с ID

Comment: Я выше использовал `$_POST['red']` а у Вас `$_POST[red]`, это тоже может валить скрипт

Answer (score 0):

Подобным образом Вы используете **GET** запрос,

```
<a href='?red={$task['task_type']}&id={$task['id']}#zatemnenie'>Редактировать</a>
```

В запросе к бд **id** Вы правильно получили, но вот в условии вы ищите параметр из **POST** запроса, попробуйте поменять **POST** на **GET**:

```
if ($_GET['red'] === 'redTask'){
    $redtt = mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE `tasks` SET `obc`='{$_POST['obc']}', `sr`='{$_POST['sr']}', `osr`='{'$_POST['osr']'}' WHERE `id`={$_GET['id']}");
}
```

Я бы ещё рекомендовал использовать проверку на наличие ключа

```
if (isset($_GET['red']) && $_GET['red'] === 'redTask'){
    $redtt = mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE `tasks` SET `obc`='{$_POST['obc']}', `sr`='{$_POST['sr']}', `osr`='{'$_POST['osr']'}' WHERE `id`={$_GET['id']}");
}
```

**UPDATE**

Перепрочёл код... Вы ссылкой пытаетесь отправить POST запрос? Вам надо передать пост запрос через форму, или через скрипт

Comment: Я через ссылку указываю, на конкретный элементы, затем я делаю всплывающее окно где есть форма куда я вношу изменения конкретного элемента в бд, ссылку я использую как способ передать параметр указывающий на этот конкретный элемент. А в форме, да я использую метод POST, попробую сделать как вы сказали, отправлять изменения методом GET.

Comment: @ДмитрийБелый если у вас есть пост запрос в отдельной форме, достаточно просто поменять условие, потому что ссылка у вас вызывает гет запрос, или покажите форму, как она выглядит

Comment: Предварительно вытаскиваю из БД данные: `$taskTypeResultID = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `task_type` WHERE `id`={$_GET['red']}");
$taskTypeRowListID = [];
while ($rowID = mysqli_fetch_assoc($taskTypeResultID)) {
    $taskTypeRowListID[] = $rowID;
}`

Comment: @ДмитрийБелый посмотри логи, в какую ошибку валяться

Comment: Ошибки нет, просто банально нет передачи.

Comment: @ДмитрийБелый не знаю как сделать чат в теме, может репутации не хватает, я ответил Вам в вашем ответе, если нет передачи то покажите весь код формы, может быть где то в другом месте собака зарыта

Comment: @ Walfter к сожалению не работает метод предложенный Вами. Все равно не видит запрос id нужный. А вот если задать числом видит и в том и другом случае...

Answer (score 0):

Сама форма`

```
    <input type="hidden" name="red" value="redTask">
    <p>
        <strong>
            <?= $taskTypeID['name'] ?> - <?= $taskTypeID['type'] ?>
        </strong>
        <br>
        <?php if ($taskTypeID['obc'] == 1):?>
            <label for="">Выберите obc -- </label><select name="obc" id="">
                <option value="1">Да</option>
                <option value="0">Нет</option>
            </select><br>
        <?php endif;?>

        <?php if ($taskTypeID['sr'] == 1):?>
            <label for="">Выберите sr -- </label><select name="sr" id="">
                <option value="1">Да</option>
                <option value="0">Нет</option>
            </select><br>
        <?php endif;?>

        <?php if ($taskTypeID['osr'] == 1):?>
            <label for="">Выберите osr -- </label><select name="osr" id="">
                <option value="1">Да</option>
                <option value="0">Нет</option>
            </select><br>
        <?php endif;?>
    </p>
    <button type="submit">Добавить</button>
</form>`
```

Comment: Вот в форме нет пост параметра `red` но он используется в условии

Comment: Не тот кусок скопировал, так то он есть. Не знаю почему не добавило. Вот недостающая часть: `?php foreach ($taskTypeRowList as $taskType): ?>
    <form action="/" method="">
`

Comment: Когда метод у формы пуст используется GET

Comment: Спасибо, попробую.

Comment: Завтра отпишусь, пока нет доступа к полноценному рабочему месту.